# cPanel functions via php?

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I need someone to tell me if possible how to show those things via PHP.

1. Show the cPanel package name the user uses.
2. Show the total quota assigned to user.
3. Show the total bandwidth quota assigned to user.

So, how should this work.
Every user that is assigned with his account, should show his package and his quota.

This is for a WHM Module.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are able to make it through the API, for example WHMCS system have this by default. But I think you need some special access to the API. Try https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+WHM+API+1

Comment: Am trying it but am not that pro. Could someone post me the correct link so I can test please?

Comment: If you can't make a development you have only two options: pay a developer to make the job for you, or buy a plugin or a system like WHMCS that is prepared for this purposes by default. Good luck